# Camera not working in iPhone in Web Browsers in Blazor WASM

Tags: javascript, ios, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

We have written the below code in blazor WASM where we are trying to capture image of user on web browser.

**Index.razor**

```
 <div class="v-canvas">
     <video id="videoFeed" width="320" height="240" />
     <canvas class="d-none" id="currentFrame" width="320" height="240" />
 </div>
  <button @onclick="CaptureFrame">
       <span>Capture</span>
   </button>


@code {
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("startVideo", "videoFeed");

 }

 private async Task CaptureFrame()
 {
     await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<String>("getFrame", "videoFeed", "currentFrame",DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
 }

}

 [JSInvokable]
 public async Task ProcessImage(string imageString)
 {

    //Some logic

 }
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function startVideo(src) {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function (stream) {
            let video = document.getElementById(src);
            if ("srcObject" in video) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
            } else {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.webkitMatchesSelector.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            }
            video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
                video.play();
                video.webkitMatchesSelector.play();
                Play(src);
            };

            //mirror image
            video.style.webkitTransform = "scaleX(-1)";
            video.style.transform = "scaleX(-1)";
        });
    }
}


function getFrame(src, dest, dotNetHelper) {
    let video = document.getElementById(src);
    let canvas = document.getElementById(dest);
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);

    let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('ProcessImage', dataUrl);
}
```

The above solution is been published on IIS and tested on multiple devices.

This works perfectly on iPad, MacBook, Windows laptops and android phones.
For iPhones in Safari/Chrome, the video does not loads in browsers at all, even after camera permission is given.

The Reference of this code is taken from - https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-webcam-capture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution after a long time.

I had to add the below attributes in the video tag in js file.

```
    let video = document.getElementById(src);
    video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
    video.setAttribute('muted', '');
    video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
```

Hope this helps others :)